# Create Data object with .bin file Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I download file with extension of `.bin`, and now i want to pass it as argument for closure in my function. First i want to create `Data struct` object with it, but i did not found solution how to do that.

How to create Data struct with that file? Currently my code just store it from temporary location to device storage, and path look like this:

```
/Users/Necrosoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EBB5C440-10EC-4E61-8FE5-69400D39C743/data/Containers/Data/Application/2E1B1568-6205-4F5D-B4F9-987AD993D449/Documents/online_pin.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load file to memory, prefer array of Int32
2. Know your struct and size of each field, read the whole chunk, each chunk has the same size of your struct, parse each field and assign it to Swift's style struct.